# Set theories that are complete modulo finite-order arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

In a previous question, I asked whether there can be effectively axiomatizable set theories (at least as strong as, say, ZF) that are complete modulo first-order arithmetic, to which the answer is no; there will be sentences of second-order arithmetic that can't be proved even using the omega-rule. I'm now curious whether there can be set theories that are complete modulo finite-order arithmetic (in the comments of my last question, someone claimed the answer was no without proof, but he has since deleted his comment). That is, for any effectively axiomatizable set theory at least as strong as ZF, will there be a sentence independent of it with no arithmetic consequences?

Comment: Your example is confusing because  $CH$ is a finite-order arithmetic sentence.

Comment: Link to OP's previous question: [Incompleteness theorems for theories with omega-rule](//mathoverflow.net/q/374061)

Comment: I didn't know that CH is a finite-order arithmetic sentence. Where on the arithmetic hierarchy does it lie?

Comment: CH is not in the arithmetic hierarchy, which refers to first-order arithmetic. It's a $\Sigma^2_1$ sentence of third-order arithmetic (unless I've overlooked something).

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the CH example in that case.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that by theory $T\supseteq \mathsf{ZF}$ "complete modulo finite-order arithmetic" you mean that the theory $T^*=(T+\text{true }\Sigma^{<\omega}_{<\omega}\text{-sentences})$ is complete? Note that Godel's second incompleteness theorem is applicable to the case of $T^*$. If $T^*$ is consistent, it couldn't prove its own consistency. The adaptation of the proof is simply reduced to the verification that provability predicate for $T^*$ satisfies Hilbert-Bernays-Lob conditions. By adapted Rosser's theorem we even get that $T^*$ should be either inconsistent or incomplete.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov Can $T^*$ even *state* its own consistency?

Comment: @none Yes, of course. The definition of $T^*$ clearly could be carried out in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Since $T^*\supseteq T\supseteq \mathsf{ZF}$ this definition could be carried out in $T^*$.  Now $T^*$ is consistent is simply the sentence "there are no proof of contradiction from the axioms of $T^*$".

Comment: @FedorPakhomov what I meant was, unless I misunderstood something, $T^*$ is not effectively axiomitizeable, so I don't see how to build up a consistency formula the way it's done for something like PA.  $T^*$ contains many sentences that are not consequenes of ZF if your definition of $T^*$ means what it looks like.  I'm still confused but I'm probably missing something silly.